# Spring MV 3.2 Exception Response Mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, exception, httpresponse

Spring 3.2.15, MVC-based REST API here (*not* Spring Boot, sadly!). I am trying to implement an exception mapper/handler that meets the following criteria:

- No matter what happens (success or error), the Spring app always returns a response entity of `MyAppResponse` (see below); and
- In the event of processing a request successfully, return an HTTP status of 200 (typical); and
- In the event of processing a request and an exception occurs, I need to control the mapping of the specific exception to a particular HTTP status code

  - Spring MVC framework errors (such as `BlahException`) must map to HTTP 422
  - Custom app exceptions, such as my `FizzBuzzException` have their own status mapping schemes:

    - `FizzBuzzException` -> HTTP 401
    - `FooBarException` -> HTTP 403
    - `OmgException` -> HTTP 404
  - All other exceptions, that is, non-Spring exceptions, and non-custom app exceptions (the 3 listed above), should produce an HTTP 500

Where the `MyAppResponse` object is:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
@Canonical
class MyAppResponse {
    String detail
    String randomNumber
}
```

It *appears* like `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` might be able to do this for me, but I'm not seeing the forest through the trees w.r.t. how it gets passed arguments. I'm hoping I can do something like:

```
// Groovy-pseudo code
@ControllerAdvice
class MyAppExceptionMapper extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleFizzBuzzException(FizzBuzzException fbEx, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status) {
        // TODO: How to reset status to 401?
        status = ???

        new ResponseEntity(fbEx.message, headers, status)
    }

    ResponseEntity<Object> handleFooBarException(FooBarException fbEx, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status) {
        // TODO: How to reset status to 403?
        status = ???

        new ResponseEntity(fbEx.message, headers, status)
    }

    ResponseEntity<Object> handleOmgException(OmgException omgEx, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status) {
        // TODO: How to reset status to 404?
        status = ???

        new ResponseEntity(omgEx.message, headers, status)
    }

    // Now map all Spring-generated exceptions to 422
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllSpringExceptions(SpringException springEx, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status) {
        // TODO: How to reset status to 422?
        status = ???

        new ResponseEntity(springEx.message, headers, status)
    }

    // Everything else is a 500...
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllOtherExceptions(Exception ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status) {
        // TODO: How to reset status to 500?
        status = ???

        new ResponseEntity("Whoops, something happened. Lol.", headers, status)
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can fully implement this mapping logic and the requirement for the entity to be a `MyAppResponse` instance and not just a string?

Then, is annotating the class with `@ControllerAdvice` the only thing that I need to do to configure Spring to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reduce @bond-java-bond answer you do not need to build `ResponseEntity` by yourself:

1. Use `@ResponseStatus` for each `handleSomeException` method (e.g. `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)`)
2. Return custom `MyAppResponse` from those methods

But if each kind of exceptions will be processed by the same way (diffs by HTTP status only) I suggest to reduce `MyAppExceptionMapper` like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAppExceptionMapper {
    private final Map<Class<?>, HttpStatus> map;
    {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(FizzBuzzException.class, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        map.put(FooBarException.class, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        map.put(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        /* List Spring specific exceptions here as @bond-java-bond suggested */
        map.put(Exception.class, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    // Handle all exceptions
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse> handleException(Exception exception) {
        MyAppResponse response = new MyAppResponse();
        // Fill response with details

        HttpStatus status = map.get(exception.getClass());
        if (status == null) {
            status = map.get(Exception.class);// By default
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, status);
    }
}
```

Pros:

1. Pretty short.
2. No code duplication.
3. Slightly more effective.
4. Easy to extend.

Also, you can move mapping configuration outside and inject it.

**How to configure MVC Dispatcher Servlet**

First of all, check if `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` (or another `contextConfigLocation` from `web.xml`) contains:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="base.package"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Secondly, check if @ControllerAdvice annotated class and @Controller annotated class both belong to subpackage of `base.package`.

See complete examples at [Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) or [Spring MVC @ExceptionHandler Example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Gregory.K (+1) - please see my comment underneath Bond's answer. I have the same question for you! Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb, I've just added "How to configure MVC Dispatcher Servlet" section.

Answer (score 1):

First the  error / exception handler should *not* worry about the success response.

Thus the responsibility of success response should lie with controller (*plain or REST controller*) method(s) annotated with `@RequestMapping` as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public MyAppResponse doSomething() { .... }
```

For mapping a particular HTTP response code with exception(s) simply write a `@ControllerAdvice` as below (*no additional configuration required*)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    // Handle FizzBuzzException with status code as 401
    @ExceptionHandler(value = FizzBuzzException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse> handleException(FizzBuzzException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse>(buildResponse(ex), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    // Handle FooBarException with status code as 403
    @ExceptionHandler(value = FooBarException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse> handleException(FooBarException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse>(buildResponse(ex), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    // Handle OmgException with status code as 404
    @ExceptionHandler(value = OmgException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse> handleException(OmgException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse>(buildResponse(ex), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    // handle Spring MVC specific exceptions with status code 422
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class, HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class, HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class,
        HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class, MissingPathVariableException.class, MissingServletRequestParameterException.class, ServletRequestBindingException.class,
        ConversionNotSupportedException.class, TypeMismatchException.class, HttpMessageNotReadableException.class, HttpMessageNotWritableException.class, MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
        MissingServletRequestPartException.class, BindException.class, NoHandlerFoundException.class, AsyncRequestTimeoutException.class})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse> handleException(Exception ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse>(buildResponse(ex), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }

    // Handle rest of the exception(s) with status code as 500
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse> handleException(Exception ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<MyAppResponse>(buildResponse(ex), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    private MyAppResponse buildResponse(Throwable t) {
        MyAppResponse response = new MyAppResponse();
        // supply value to response object
        return response;
    }
}
```

Let know in comments if any further information is required.

**P.S.**: List of Spring MVC exception [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html#handleException-java.lang.Exception-org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest-)

Comment: Thanks @Bond - Java Bond (+1) - however either Spring doesn't seem to be finding my handler (and treating it as `@ControllerAdvice`) or Tomcat is somehow mucking things up (this is a Spring MVC REST service deployed as a WAR to Tomcat 7). If I hardcode `throw new FizzBuzzException()` in a controller method, the HTTP response entity/body is HTML that Tomcat sends back. Inside that HTML is the `FizzBuzzException` stacktrace...but that's not what I need/want. I need the HTTP response to be serialized JSON representing my `MyAppResponse` class. Do I need to do anything in my servlet XML?