# How to handle wrapped exceptions in a Spring Exception Handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

## The context

In our application we have started using `CompletableFuture` but as we introduce it in existing code, we sometimes have to call the [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--) (or `join()`) method.

These methods wrap any exception that occurred during the process into an `ExecutionException` (respectively a `CompletionException`).

## The problem

By default, Spring Web MVC would handle these exceptions by returning a 500 HTTP status. We would like instead to unwrap their cause, and delegate their handling to the corresponding custom exception handler.

As opposed to what is said in [*handling wrapped exceptions in spring mvc*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529757/525036), rethrowing the cause does not work¹ and [Spring simply logs a debug message with it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9c97585f3d0ed26cf7fa51723629fc47fb4fa75c/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java#L370-L372).

On the other side, [*How to rethrow exception as @ResponseStatus-annotated exception in Spring @ExceptionHandler?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077573/how-to-rethrow-exception-as-responsestatus-annotated-exception-in-spring-excep) is too specific as it supposes that we know in advance the cause of the exception and how to handle it.

The solution that we found is to define a `@ControllerAdvice` that delegates the handling of the cause back to the [`HandlerExceptionResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) like this:

```
@Autowired
HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver;

@ExceptionHandler(ExecutionException.class)
public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ExecutionException e) {
   return handlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, null, (Exception) e.getCause());
}
```

However this looks a bit like a hack. I fear that it could break in future versions of Spring, or if for some reason there is more than one `HandlerExceptionResolver` in the context.

What's the right way to do this?

¹ <sub>Edit: this used to be the accepted answer on that question but it appears to have been deleted in the meantime.</sub>

Comment: Did you look at this? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190981/spring-mv-3-2-exception-response-mapping

Comment: @ritesh.garg This looks more like a general question about how to implement exception handlers. What we need is a generic way to handle an exception's cause in a handler – without having an `instanceof` for each possible type that it could have.

Comment: There **IS** more than one HandlerExceptionResolver in the context: I've tried to debug your solution (thanks btw) and the handler is instance  of _HandlerExceptionResolverComposite_ which holds the resolver list and iterates through it. So I believe it should work fine.

Comment: Have you run into any issues with this approach? This seems to be the cleanest solution to the problem.  The answer to the question marked as duplicate doesn't work for me, and even so requires casting to every possible type of exception that could possibly be wrapped in a CompletionException.  Too bad this was shut down as a duplicate, the other answer isn't acceptable.

Comment: @brub I don't have access to the code now but I think we stayed with that, and didn't have any issue so far.

Comment: The provided work around didn't work for me as our `@ControllerAdvice` had `basePackages` set. I needed to pass a `HandlerMethod` through to `resolveException()`. You can autowire it into your method parameters.

Comment: The problem jazd mentioned is real. However, if you have 2 ControllerAdvice classes and both need to handle wrapped exceptions, this gets tricky. If you add in the HandlerMethod to the method parameters, then this is for whichever ControllerAdvice is handling the wrapped exception. If Advice A is used to unwrap the exception, then when iterating over handlers in the 'resolveException' call it will use the wrong HandlerMethod when delegating to Advice B. This is a problem if it uses basePackages or annotation attribute of the @ControllerAdvice annotation as the wrong annotation will be checked.